# Is it possible to delay resolving a .weakreference in gcc-as until link time? (GCC)

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm, firmware

If you want to declare *.weakreference* for a set of interrupt vectors such as:

```
.weakreference ISR_SPI_HANDLER, defaultExceptionHandler
```

in a startup.S file or some framework include, it's very useful except that if you then declare *ISR_SPI_HANDLER* as a function in your main.c file, *ISR_SPI_HANDLER* in the startup.S still resolves to *defaultExceptionHandler* because .*weakreference* only works in local scope (terminology? pre-linking). However, .*weak* functions as it's expected, and allows you to "override" the definition with a definition in main.c, but if you don't, you'll always resolve to 0x00, which is inferior obviously to resolving to a default vector.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Post your alternate solution as a separate answer, not as part of the question, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the `.weakref` in the assembler.  Instead just use `ISR_SPI_HANDLER` as an external.  The assembler naturally wants to optimize to PC relative jumps to known locations.  You are fighting this and someone else will want the call to `defaultExceptionHandler`.

Instead use [the linker](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Builtin-Functions.html#Builtin-Functions),

```
  .text : {
    *(.text);
    ISR_SPI_HANDLER = DEFINED(ISR_SPI_HANDLER) ? ISR_SPI_HANDLER : defaultExceptionHandler;
    …
  }
```

Alternatively, split *startup.S* with the `.weak`, `.set` and `defaultExceptionHandler` declaration in one file and another that is using/calling `ISR_SPI_HANDLER`.

> However, .weak functions as it's expected, and allows you to "override" the definition with a definition in main.c, but if you don't, you'll always resolve to 0x00, which is inferior obviously to resolving to a default vector.

The typical case is define a function and use `.weak` in the same file.  Ie, you need to use `.weak` where the routine is defined (but another object files may override this).  To achieve this and keep `defaultExceptionHandler` for other uses,

```
   .weak ISR_SPI_HANDLER
   .set ISR_SPI_HANDLER, defaultExceptionHandler
```

For ARM Thumb code, you may need `.thumb_set` instead.  I believe this is the effect you wanted.

Why `.weakref`?  I think that this is better suited to machine generated code such as a compiler would generate.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I need. I didn't know I could use that terminology in the linker file. I am not sure about your alternative suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

**NEW SOLUTION:**

Apparently, you can use `.weak NAME` to make it an external symbol and then `.set NAME VALUE` to give it a different default value than 0x0